# VSTS cannot query teams

Tags: azure-devops

For the **Assigned To** Operator I've tried **In** as well as **In Group** but it always shows no results match the query.
I've checked that there are team members in the group and that there are bugs assigned to the team members.
This query used to work in TFS2012, but since we upgraded and migrated to cloud my query doesn't work any more. What am I missing here?

Image of Query:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It look to be working now so I assume you suppose to make upgrade to latest version.
[image]